# Pros and Cons of populating UITable entries from UISearchBar from code vs text file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to learn how to use the UISearchBar and I found two sites that teach it differently. One teaches it by initializing an array of object(?) named Candy. In the setup it has the description of each Candy object.

```
  //MARK: - Properties
  var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
  var candies = [Candy]()

  // MARK: - View Setup
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    candies = [
        Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Chocolate Bar"),
        Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Chocolate Chip"),
        Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Dark Chocolate"),
        Candy(category:"Hard", name:"Lollipop"),
        Candy(category:"Hard", name:"Candy Cane"),
        Candy(category:"Hard", name:"Jaw Breaker"),
        Candy(category:"Other", name:"Caramel"),
        Candy(category:"Other", name:"Sour Chew"),
        Candy(category:"Other", name:"Gummi Bear")
    ]
```

On a separate site teaching how to use the UISearchBar, it grabbed a list of countries from a text file and loaded it into the table view.

```
let pathToFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "countries", ofType: "txt")
if let path = pathToFile {
    do {
        let countriesString = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        dataArray = countriesString.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        tblSearchResults.reloadData()
    }
    catch let error {
        print ("error occured \(error)")
    }
}
```

For someone who is trying to learn app development, is there a preferred method over the other one? Is there a better way to do this other than the 2 ways mentioned above? I would guess that the first method allows a more straightforward way of handling the data vs an external file that you have to call.

Comment: Always keep your data separate from your code. What if that data were used by different classes that don't communicate?  If the data is in one file, then you only have one file to maintain.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it doesn't matter which way the table is being populated (even though in both cases an array loads the table view) because you are learning how the UISearchBar works, not the TableViewDatasource. IMO: Follow the Candy example. When you're confident you understand what is going on, read the one that loads the data from the text file. You should understand 99% of the second tutorial (with the exception of how it loads its array from a text file.)

Comment: Great! Do you guys know a place that explains how to set up a search bar and a tableview together?